# I don't understand the string diagram of hypergraphs, can someone explain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, hypergraphs

[image]In the paper [Decorated Cospsans](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.00872) by Brendan Fong, they gave the definition

Let (X) be an object in a symmetric monoidal category with a special commutative Frobenius structure $(X, \mu_X, \delta_X, \eta_X, \epsilon_X)$. The following equations hold:

\begin{align}
    \mu_{X \otimes Y} &= (\mu_X \otimes \mu_Y) \circ (1_X \otimes \sigma_{YX} \otimes 1_Y) \\
    \eta_{X \otimes Y} &= \eta_X \otimes \eta_Y \\
    \delta_{X \otimes Y} &= (1_X \otimes \sigma_{XY} \otimes 1_Y) \circ (\delta_X \otimes \delta_Y) \\
    \epsilon_{X \otimes Y} &= \epsilon_X \otimes \epsilon_Y
\end{align}

and in the paper [Hypergraph Categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.08304) by Brendan Fong and David I. Spivak they defined by string diagrams in the following way in image. But isn't the first diagram is of the only part $1_X \otimes \sigma_{YX} \otimes 1_Y$? where did the $\mu_X \otimes \mu_Y$ part go?
[image]
i have also added the string diagram which I drew and acoording to me should be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the right-hand side of the first diagram,

[image]

The crossing of two wires is $\sigma_{YX}$. So that right-hand diagram shows $1_X\otimes \sigma_{YX}\otimes 1_Y$

[image]

composed with $\mu_X\otimes \mu_Y$

[image]

So the overall diagram is $(\mu_X\otimes \mu_Y)\circ(1_X\otimes \sigma_{YX}\otimes 1_Y)$.

[image]

Note that the $\circ$ notation swaps the order of the two morphisms. Some people write composition the other way around, so that this expression would be written $(1_X\otimes \sigma_{YX}\otimes 1_Y);(\mu_X\otimes \mu_Y)$. That way the order of the algebraic notation matches that of the diagram.

Comment: But isn't the black dot mean tensor? should the first diagram not be connected? i have eddit the question please see the picture which i drew to see what I mean. thanks

Comment: I understood it. thanks.

Comment: @RabiaSagheer just in case: the black dot represents $\mu$ rather than the tensor. The tensor is indicated by drawing wires in parallel.

Comment: @N.Virgo https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151020/applied-category-theory